# dynamic button calling from another class

Tags: java, android

I am new in java/Android, I want to pass method where i have defined my button property. and the the method is is written in another class which can not implement the Activity.

```
ex

class ViewProvider extends xyz
{
 public Button getButton(){
       Button one=new Button();
       one.setText("abc");
       one.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
       //and other properties like color,Gravity ect 
       return one
    }
}

Class calcu extends Activity{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_list);
        ViewProvider v=new ViewProvider();
       RelativeLayout relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
       relativelayout.addView(v.getButton);
       setContentView(relativelayout);

       }
```

But i am getting an error

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an Activity data type and initialize it through constructor as below

```
class ViewProvider extends xyz
   Activity activity;
{

     public ViewProvider(Activity activity, JSONObject json) {
                      this.activity = activity;
                 }

    public Button getButton(activity){
    Button one=new Button();
    one.setText("abc");
    return one
}
```

**then call the method as below on onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)**

```
ViewProvider v=new ViewProvider(this);
      RelativeLayout relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
      relativelayout.addView(v.getButton);
      setContentView(relativelayout);
```

Comment: @user3232134 why do you need a button to be initialized in a different class? when all you do is initialize and return button object

Comment: @Raghunandan  Because i want to reuse it in different activities...so i want this approach..is there any better way or suggestion??

Comment: @user3232134 you can intialize button in different activities itself. But you can't use the button of one activity in another. Even in your case you will need context passed as param to the construcotr of `ViewProvider`. To resue have a button in one layout. then you can use include tag to include the layout any where you want in other layouts. set the layouts to respective activities

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the suggestion i will try in that way as well, but above code is working fine as well. is ther any performance or any other issue with above code

Comment: @user3232134 nothing till now. but it is not necessary. Don't know what you want to do further with the above code. So can't comment further

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the constructors of button @ you have wrong params.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

```
Button(Context context)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

All the three take context as a param.

I would suggest you to read the docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Also you have `setContentView` twice which is not necessary.

Have the button initialized in activity itself

```
  Class calcu extends Activity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       RelativeLayout relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
       Button one=new Button(this);
       one.setText("abc");
       relativelayout.addView(one);
       setContentView(relativelayout);
   }
   }
```